# How to remove data points from a data set in Matlab

Tags: matlab, vector, curve-fitting, data-manipulation, data-fitting

In Matlab, I have a vector that is a 1x204 double. It represents a biological signal over a certain period of time and over that time the signal varies - sometimes it peaks and goes up and sometimes it remains relatively small, close to the baseline value of 0. I need to plot this the reciprocal of this data (on the xaxis) against another set of data (on the y-axis) in order to do some statistical analysis.

The problem is that due to those points close to 0, for e.g. the smallest point I have is = -0.00497, 1/0.00497 produces a value of -201 and turns into an "outlier", while the rest of the data is very different and the values not as large. So I am trying to remove the very small values close to 0, from the data set so that it does not affect 1/value.

I know that I can use the cftool to remove those points from the plot, but how do I get the vector with those points removed? Is there a way of actually removing the points? From the cftool and removing those points on the original, I was able to generate the code and find out which exact points they are, but I don't know how to create a vector with those points removed.

Can anyone help?

I did try using the following for loop to get it to remove values, with 'total_BOLD_time_course' being my signal and '1/total_BOLD_time_course' is what I want to plot, but the problem with this is that in my if statement total_BOLD_time_course(i) = 1, which is not exactly true - so by doing this the points still exist in the vector but are now taking the value 1. But I just want them to be gone from the vector.

```
for i = 1:204 
  if total_BOLD_time_course(i) < 0 && total_BOLD_time_course(i) < -0.01
   total_BOLD_time_course(i) = 1;

  else if total_BOLD_time_course(i) > 0 && total_BOLD_time_course(i) < 0.01
     total_BOLD_time_course(i) = 1 ;
  end
 end
end
```

Comment: Not sure what you actually want. If you have tried writing some code, please post it? We could then show you how to fix it.

Comment: Hi Sanjay, I have added part of the code I used but I don't think it makes sense given what i want. To explain very basically say I have  A = [0.01 2 5 0.001 2.3], I want to remove any points that are for close to 0, so here I'd want 0.01 and 0.001, but I don't know how to. The for loop I posted would give me A = [1 2 5 1 2.3] but I want 0.01 and 0.001 to be gone from the vector completely so that when I do plot(A) it doesn't look weird, those points are just excluded. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: I think it's better that you understand your data first. Then you can decide on what method to apply. It might be good enough to just say `if x< 0.1 then x=0` or you might want to use the standard deviation to determine what is an outlier. It's up to you to decide what the best method is for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove points from an array, use the syntax

```
total_BOLD_time_course( abs(total_BOLD_time_course<0.01) ) = nan
```

that makes them 'blank' on the graph, and ignored by further calculations, but without destroying the temporal sequence of the datapoints.

If actually destroying timepoints is not a concern then do

```
total_BOLD_time_course( abs(total_BOLD_time_course<0.01) ) = []
```

Then there'll be fewer data points, and they won't map on to any other `time_course` you have. But the advantage is that it will "close up" the gaps in the graph.

--
PS

note that in your code, the phrase

```
x<0 && x<-0.01
```

is redundant because if any number is less than -0.01, it is automatically less than 0. I believe the first should be `x>0`, and then your code is fine.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Making the values nan worked perfectly. Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 1):

As [VHarisop](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2444293/vharisop) suggests, you can set a threshold for outliers and exclude them. But, depending on your plot, it might be important to ensure that the remaining data are not shunted horizontally to fill the gaps.   To plot `1./y` as a function of `x`, you could either just `plot(x, 1./y)` and then set the y limits with `ylim` to exclude the outliers from view,  or use NaNs:

```
e = 0.01
y( abs(y) < e ) = nan;
plot( x, 1./y )
```

For quantitative (non-visual) statistical analysis, either remove the values entirely from `y` as suggested—bearing in mind that this leaves you with a shorter vector—or use statistics functions that know how to treat NaNs as missing data (`nanmean`, `nanstd`, etc).

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, you can. You might want to define a threshold, like `e = 0.01`, and cut off all vector elements whose absolute value is below e. 
Example:

```
# assuming v is your initial vector
e = 0.01
new_vector = v(abs(v) > e);
```

Alternatively, you could use the [excludedata](http://www.mathworks.com/help/curvefit/excludedata.html) tool from the Curve Fitting Toolbox, since you know the indices of the vector elements you want to exlude.